# Solr improve Search speed

Tags: search, solr

in solr search how to optimizing to improve Solr search Speed. I try with different Cache mechanism but not work.we are using 65 million record to search using solr search.it takes approx. 45 sec. to search. but i want to search 65 million record approx. 5-10 sec. so friend suggest me to reduce the search time.
i am using Apache Solr (Ver. 5.2.1) .

Comment: what version of solr are you using?

Comment: please allow us to know what have you tried so far

Comment: There is absolutely not enough information here. You need to reduce your test case to absolute essential and ask a more concrete question with example and identified challenge. I would also suggest that Solr User mailing list might be a better forum than here for that kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple core where in you can split your data into different cores. As the data gets divided/split in different cores, the search is limited to the core and limited indexed data which could improve your search speed.

In my case I have data of different category so created the cores for each category. Cores are created by category name. When a search request comes for a category, the search request is made only to that category.

The second approach is you can do the sharding which will again split the data into different shard. Here each shard will hold the index data.

When data is too large for one node, you can break it up and store it in sections by creating one or more shards. Each is a portion of the logical index, or core, and it's the set of all nodes containing that section of the index.

It is highly recommended that you use SolrCloud when needing to scale up or scale out.

Below are the links which will help you on the solrCloud

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud